# How to --dry-run an endorsement or baking operation?

Tags: baking

With the Tezos client, we can `--dry-run` an operation to test if the setup is working correctly (e.g., remote signer, Nano Ledger, etc.).

Is there any way to `--dry-run` an endorsement or baking operation for the same purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is no, it's not possible.